# Observer or Pub/Sub for dashboard (Springboot)

Tags: design-patterns, spring-boot

We have a manufacturing plant and there is a single sql table that is regularly updated with every resource's running job and status. I want to have clients subscribe to changes (by dept) in a web app. (we are building a new microservice architecture for this and other functions). Dept supervisors want to see a "real-time" status of the department's resources and jobs. Probably a total of 20-30 users

Which pattern is best: pub/sub or observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Publisher / Subscriber** each time a status is change you publish a message and subcriber will update the information ,you can filter out message based on department and decide whether to update the infor or not.

**Observable** will notify all the linked members only.

Suggested way is to go for Pub/Sub

Any new addition or deletion of services will be easy.